# “ERROR TypeError: Object(…) is not a function” using UniqueDeviceID

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, deviceid

I followed the instructions at: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/unique-device-id/ and the `version 5.0.0` is installed

**ts file** :

```
import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx';   

constructor(private uniqueDeviceID: UniqueDeviceID) { }

this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
        .then((uuid: any) => console.log(uuid))
        .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

In **app.module.ts** :

```
import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx';

providers: [
    StatusBar,
    UniqueDeviceID,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

**Error** :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a chance. Initilation like that in App.module.ts

```
    providers: [
     StatusBar,
     SplashScreen,
     {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
     UniqueDeviceID
   ]
```

also run this in ngOnInit in App.component.ts

```
    this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
     .then((uuid: any) => console.log(uuid))
     .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```